# Invalid entity ref adding SalesOrder in Netsuite

Tags: .net, netsuite

So I have the following code to add a sales order in netsuite and I pass it the internalId of a customer I just created and updated using the same internalId.
I keeps giving me an error saying Invalid entity reference and quoting the internalId I gave it. In the following example "NetsuiteID" is the internalId returned from creating the customer record with the same API.

```
//Create the sales order
    com.netsuite.webservices.SalesOrder salesOrder = new SalesOrder();

    //this links it to a customer
    salesOrder.entity = new RecordRef() { internalId = NetsuiteID, type = RecordType.customer, typeSpecified = true };

    SalesOrderItem salesItem = new SalesOrderItem();
    salesItem.item = new RecordRef() { "200" }; 

    SalesOrderItemList itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
    SalesOrderItem[] items = new SalesOrderItem[1];
    items[0] = salesItem;
    itemList.item = items;
    salesOrder.itemList = itemList;

    WriteResponse salesResp = netsuite.add(salesOrder);
```

Utterly confused by this, all examples I see on this site in .NET or PHP show that using the internalId should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I clipped out a snippet from Netsuite's sample application.  The only real difference I can tell is that they specified a name and an internalid for the customer object (I'd be surprised if that was mandatory though).

```
using NSClientERP.com.netsuite.webservices;
//...

SalesOrder so = new SalesOrder();
//...
// res was an object from a result of a saved search for a customer
//...
RecordRef customer = new RecordRef();
customer.type = RecordType.customer;
customer.typeSpecified = true;
System.String entID = ((Customer) (res.recordList[0])).entityId;
customer.name = entID;
customer.internalId = ((Customer) (res.recordList[0])).internalId;
so.entity = customer;
```